# Future.wait function

Tags: dart, flutter

```
class Tickets extends StatefulWidget {
  int groupid;
  int event_id;
  List returnTickets = [];

  Map<String, dynamic> hey;

  Tickets([this.groupid,this.event_id,this.hey,this.returnTickets]);

  @override
  _TicketsState createState() => new _TicketsState();
}

class _TicketsState extends State<Tickets> {
  List returnTickets = [];
  List ticketType = [];
  Map<String, dynamic> hey;

  int i = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
//    _getTicketType();


  }

  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widget.groupid;
    widget.event_id;



    var futureBuilder = new FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.wait([hey, returnTickets]).then(
            (response) => new _TicketsState(hey: response[0], returnTickets: response[1]),
      ),

      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.connectionState);
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Text('...');
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else
              return createListTickets(context, snapshot);
        }
      },
    );
```

[image: Error for the Future.wait]

Hi everyone, I am trying to implement the Future.wait function so then I can hopefully use more than a method within a building widget, but as I am trying to do so, I get this long error, any help please??
Thank you in advance, much appreciated.

Comment: Future.wait expects a List<Future> `hey` and `returnTickets` are not a future, they are a Map and a list respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not recommended to use what is called "raw" types in Dart2 (`List`). In this particular case, `Future.wait` expects a `List<Future>`, but you've (implicitly) created a `List<Object>` here:

```
List returnTickets = [];
```

This worked in Dart1, because `List<dynamic>` could pretend to be `List<T>`.

Try writing:

```
List<Future> returnTickets = [];
```

Or, better yet:

```
final returnTickets = <Future>[];
```